# tensorfow addon problems while downloading rasa on my mac os

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa

I tried downgrading python to 3.6 and upgraded pip yet no changes. This error shows up while downloading Rasa.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons<=0.12,>=0.10 (from rasa) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons<=0.12,>=0.10 (from rasa)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have to manually install the correct version of tensorflow-addons before installing rasa.

Try

```
pip install tensorflow-addons==0.11.2
```

and then install rasa again

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons==0.11.2 (from versions: none). While running it